# Add a new Row in DataGridView with incremented value every time the event is fired

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a table which has an ID, Name, and ActiveStatus which are set to default on a button click event. Whenever I click, it adds a new row to the datagridview but does nothing if i want to add a new row under it WITH AN INCREMENT VALUE OF PREVIOUS VALUE. Like if there is already an id with number 1 is present, it should add a new row with id = 2. or if it is empty, it should add id = 1.

```
   MyDatabase mydata = new MyDatabase();
   List<MyDatabase> listmydata = new List<MyDatabase>();

        mydata.id = "1";
        mydata.Name = "YO";
        mydata.ActiveStatus= true;
        listmydata.Add(mydata);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = listmydata.ToList<MyDatabase>();
```

//This adds only 1 new row, does nothing if we click the button again

Comment: Please add the listener and the DB schema to the question

Comment: `List<MyDatabase> listmydata = new List<MyDatabase>();`: you're creating a new `List<MyDatabase>`, add a single object to it, then use this list, with its single object, as the DataSource of your DGV. Of course just that one object is shown. Declare `listmydata` somewhere else (as a Field, probably, your context is not clear) then add elements to it when needed. Possibly, post the actual type of `MyDatabase`. Also, give a look at the `BindingSource` class. It's also not clear how ASP.Net is related to WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to announce a global class variable, wich will count your new elements, wich you can use as id field in MyDatabase list.

```
public class Form...
{
   private int elemsCount = 0;
   public event(...)
   {
      MyDatabase mydata = new MyDatabase();
      List<MyDatabase> listmydata = new List<MyDatabase>();

      mydata.id = elemsCount.ToString();
      mydata.Name = "YO";
      mydata.ActiveStatus= true;
      listmydata.Add(mydata);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = listmydata.ToList<MyDatabase>();
      elemsCount++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Give "up" to my answer please

Comment: I would love to but my reputation is low to give anyone any upvote.

Comment: @SarthakNarang You can tap to "check mark" button, wich is under "down button".

Comment: @SarthakNarang TY

Comment: Glad you helped.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Vladimir's answer, I would suggest you need a global variable to keep count of how many times this method has been executed.  However, you're probably going to want to make your List variable global as well.

```
public class YourClass
{
   private int numExecutions = 0;
   private List<MyDatabase> listmydata = new List<MyDatabase>();
   public YourEvent(EventArgs e)
   {  
      MyDatabase mydata = new MyDatabase();
      mydata.id = numExecutions.toString();
      mydata.Name = "YO";
      mydata.ActiveStatus= true;
      listmydata.Add(mydata);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = listmydata.ToList<MyDatabase>();
      numExecutions++;
   }
}
```